# Allow Secondary Logon (Run As) to a specific exe only

Tags: windows, windows-xp, credentials, access-control

Is it possible to disable `Secondary Logon (Run As)` to all programs except for one? If yes, how?

If not, is it possible to always run a specific program as administrator without using `Secondary Logon (Run As)`?

Comment: you can hide the explorer shortcuts for it, but I don't believe you can completely disable it (it would still work from the command line) unless you removed or renamed the executable. there isn't any file metadata that would allow the os to decide what executables could be runas'd and which ones couldn't.

Comment: @FrankThomas I tried using `/savecred` in the shortcut parameter but it doesn't appear to store the credentials after reboot, or is that possible? I am using it in a Guest account BTW.